# Undefined symbol error: the target library has been set in rpath but it still cannot be found

Tags: boost, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors, dynamic-linking

```
calving@norfolk:~/sandbox/stage/third_party/houdini16.5/lib$ ldd libgusd.so | grep boost
    libboost_python.so.1.55.0 => /home/calveng/sandbox/stage/third_party/houdini16.5/lib/./../../../lib/libboost_python.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f735cb9c000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.55.0 => /home/calveng/sandbox/stage/third_party/houdini16.5/lib/./../../../lib/./libboost_regex.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f735af6a000)
calving@norfolk:~/sandbox/stage/third_party/houdini16.5/lib$ readelf -s --wide libgusd.so | grep _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
    1064: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
    6632: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
```

Once I try to link this "libgusd.so" library, it will throw an error: "undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv"

But the point is the path which including boost has already been set by an embedded rpath, and some other boost file can be linked properly.

Does anybody ran into similar condition before? Any prompt would be really helpful.

TIPS: There isn't a LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my environment, so no overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it solved by:

patchelf --add-needed libboost_system.so.1.55.0 libgusd.so

I guess I still a little confusing about the difference between linked-libraries and their paths... I thought all of the dynamic libraries will be linked automatically once the program needs them.